# How To Download Web Client Side Data As A File Using The Dart Language

Tags: dart

I have some data on the client web browser (e.g. a string from a textarea) in my Dart web application. I would like to allow the User to download the text as a file. How can I do this? I do not want to use server side code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Client side download can be performed with the following code:

```
  void downloadFileToClient(String filename, String text){
    AnchorElement tl = document.createElement('a');
    tl..attributes['href'] = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + Uri.encodeComponent(text)
      ..attributes['download'] = filename
      ..click();   
  }
```

This depends on browser support for the **download** attribute on anchor tags. Check your target platform for suitability.

The CanIUse site gives a [status](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) across browser platforms and versions.

Comment: This seemed too wonderful to be real - and like CanIUse said, it doesn't work on Safari, which is sadly the browser most iphoneusers use...do you have any Idea how to do the same for safari - without having to first save a file serverside?